# Is the collapse of $PH$ known to extend downward to classes in-between its levels?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, polynomial-hierarchy

Contained in-between each level of the polynomial hierarchy are various complexity classes, including $\Delta_i^{\text{P}}$, $\text{DP}$, $\text{BH}_k$, and $\Sigma_i^\text{P} \cap \Pi_i^\text{P}$. For lack of better terminology, I will refer to these and any others as *intermediate classes* between levels $i$ and $i+1$ in the polynomial hierarchy. For the purposes of this question, assume they are the classes contained in $\Sigma_{i+1}^\text{P} \cap \Pi_{i+1}^\text{P}$ but contain $\Sigma_i^\text{P}$ and/or $\Pi_i^\text{P}$. We want to avoid including $\Sigma_{i+1}^\text{P} \cap \Pi_{i+1}^\text{P}$, if possible, as it is trivially equivalent to $\text{PH}$ if it collapses to the ${i+1}^{th}$ level.

In addition, define the following:
$\text{DP}_i = \left \{ L \cap L' : L \in \Sigma_i^\text{P} \text{ and } L' \in \Pi_i^{\text{P}} \right \}$

The above is a generalization of the class $\text{DP}$ (also written $\text{D}^\text{P}$). In this definition, $\text{DP}$ is equivalent to $\text{DP}_1$. It is considered in another [cstheory.se question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/an-analog-of-dp-for-the-second-level-of-the-polynomial-hierarchy). It is easy to see that $\text{DP}_i \subseteq \Delta_{i+1}^{\text{P}}$ and contains both $\Sigma_i^\text{P}$ and $\Pi_i^\text{P}$.

**Reference Diagram:**

[image: Diagram of PH]

**Question:**
Suppose that the polynomial hierachy collapses to the ${i+1}^{th}$ level, but does **not** collapse to the $i^{th}$ level.  That is, $\Sigma_{i+1}^\text{P}=\Pi_{i+1}^\text{P}$ and $\Sigma_{i}^\text{P}\neq\Pi_{i}^\text{P}$.

Can we say anything more about the relationships between these intermediate classes themselves and others in any level below $i+1$? Is there a schema for a collection of complexity classes where, for every collection, the classes are equivalent if and only if the $\text{PH}$ collapses exactly to an arbitrarily chosen level?

Just as a followup, suppose that the hierarchy collapsed to any particular one of these intermediate classes (such as $\Delta_{i+1}^{\text{P}}$). Depending on the class selected, do we know if this collapse must continue to extend downwards, perhaps even to the $i^{th}$ level?

The above question was partially explored and answered in a paper by Hemaspaandra et. al:
[A Downward Collapse within the Polynomial Hierarchy](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9910007v1.pdf)
Does someone happen to know of additional examples not mentioned in this paper or have further intuition as to what needs to happen in order for a class to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have a good answer, but in the spirit of complexity, I have some answers which suggest that a good answer may be hard to come by :).

1. Note that the generalized version of Ladner's Theorem implies that there are infinitely many poly-time degrees strictly in between $\mathsf{\Sigma_i P}$ and any poly-time degree strictly above it. In particular, if the hierarchy collapses to the $i+1$-st level but not the $i$-th, then there are infinitely many p-degrees between $\mathsf{\Sigma_i P}$ and $\mathsf{\Sigma_{i+1} P} \cap \mathsf{\Pi_{i+1} P}=\mathsf{\Sigma_{i+1} P}$.
2. If I recall correctly, constructing an oracle for which $\mathsf{PH}$ looks like the arithmetic hierarchy is still an open problem. By "looks like the arithmetic hierarchy," I mean that $\mathsf{PH}$ does not collapse, and $\mathsf{\Sigma_{k} P} \cup \mathsf{\Pi_k P} \subsetneq \mathsf{\Delta_{k+1} P} = \mathsf{\Sigma_{k+1} P} \cap \mathsf{\Pi_{k+1} P}$ for all $k$. This at least suggests that the answer to your question may not be known.
3. [Ker-I Ko](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~keriko/survey2.pdf) gives oracles in which he separates the levels of $\mathsf{BPH}$ from those of $\mathsf{PH}$. As these two hierarchies intertwine one another, this gives you at least some information about relativizable collapses of problems between the levels of $\mathsf{PH}$.
4. This next reference is the wrong direction, but you might also be interested in the result and its techniques. [Chang and Kadin](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/papers/closer/bhe2.pdf) showed that if the [Boolean hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bh) (which lives entirely below the second level of $\mathsf{PH}$, but extends $\mathsf{DP}$ to a whole hierarchy) collapses to its $k$-th level then $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses to the $k$-th level of the Boolean hierarchy over $\mathsf{\Sigma_2 P}$.

Comment: Should $$\mathsf{\Sigma_{k} P} \cup \mathsf{\Pi_k P} \subsetneq \mathsf{\Delta_k P} = \mathsf{\Sigma_{k+1} P} \cap \mathsf{\Pi_{k+1} P}$$ be $$\mathsf{\Delta_{k} P}=\mathsf{\Sigma_{k} P} \cup \mathsf{\Pi_k P} \subsetneq \mathsf{\Delta_{k+1} P} = \mathsf{\Sigma_{k+1} P} \cap \mathsf{\Pi_{k+1} P}?$$

Comment: sorry but I thought $\Sigma_{k-1}^P\cup\Pi_{k-1}^P\subseteq \Delta_k^P\subseteq \Sigma_k^p\cap\Pi_k^P\subseteq \Sigma_k^P\cup\Pi_k^P$ correct?

Eg: $$P=\Sigma_{0}^P\cup\Pi_{0}^P=P\cup P\subseteq \Delta_1^P=P\subseteq \Sigma_1^p\cap\Pi_1^P=NP\cap coNP\subseteq \Sigma_1^P\cup\Pi_1^P=NP\cup coNP\subseteq \Delta_2^P=P^{NP}\subseteq\Sigma_2^P\cap\Pi_2^P\subseteq\Sigma_2^P\cup\Pi_2^P\dots$$